# I have WCF(odata) services how can i get response in android

Tags: android, odata, wcfserviceclient, android-webservice

I have Wcf(Odata) Services to get database values into client mobile. how can i get response from the service and store in local database.
if you give any example it is very useful for me

Answer (score 0):

There are different possible java libraries to connect a client to a odata source. I would give one of the following a try:

- [odata4j](http://odata4j.org/)
- [Apache olingo](http://olingo.incubator.apache.org/)
- [JayData](http://jaydata.org/)

(You can find even more libraries on [odata.org](http://www.odata.org/libraries/))

Each of them is capable to read/write a odata source. For further information on storing Data on Android devices, i recommend [Android Develoeprs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: Thanks for response Daniel,

Comment: can you give example on this one get response from odata services for example for this url http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products

Comment: at http://www.odata4j.org you can see a short example, extracting all Category-Names of http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Categories

Other examples can be found within the examples/consumer source folder http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/source/browse/

Comment: i saw odata4j.org but i am getting how to do getting from this url services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Categories

Comment: i need to android code for get the response from url